# Android String Resource

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application requires about 50,000 different strings. I could store them in a database, but I was wondering if it is possible and advisable to store them as string resources.

- Is it a good approach to store lots of string in `string.xml` file?
- How many string we can store in `string.xml` file ?
- Searching Cost of `string` by name ?
  like

Code Snippet:

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
    return getString(resId);
}
```

Are there any other approach that i can use?

Comment: its very logical ..if someone can understand

Comment: But that only answers point number 2...

Comment: @OneWay not exactly..please read  the  complete question

Comment: why dont use the data in a SQLite File ?

Comment: @OneWay what type of more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a bit hard to frame this answer but let me try:

> How many string we can store in `string.xml` file ?

First at all, resources id are compiled as constants in R class. That said, in [Limitations of the Java Virtual Machine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11) say:

> The per-class or per-interface constant pool is limited to 65535 entries by the 16-bit constant_pool_count field of the ClassFile structure (§4.1). This acts as an internal limit on the total complexity of a single class or interface.

So, 50k string resources seems possible. As skeptic, after a bit of experimenting, it seems that you can have up ~33k string resources in a [new blank project](https://github.com/rnrneverdies/LargeStringResources). Beyond this limit, it produces a compile-time error "too many constants".

> Searching Cost of string by name ?

In linked project I did basic comparision between  `getResources().getIdentifier(..);` (by name) and `getResources().getString(id);` (by id).

Get by id is 13x faster than get by name.

I've also compared it with SQLite. `getResources().getIdentifier(..);` is 1.5x faster than `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'string_x'`

> Is it a good approach to store lots of string in `string.xml` file ?

IMHO, no.

**Pros:**

1. GetResurceByName it's just 1.5x faster than SQLite.

**Cons:**

1. Increase compile time significantly.
2. Guaranteed that at some point you will receive 'too many constants'.
3. It's hard to localize. The `2^16` limit involves all translations.

> Another Approach?

This post could help you to ship the application with a pre populated database with your app: [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database?answertab=votes#tab-top)